# Trying to use SDL 2 with Visual Studio c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sdl-2

I am trying to do one that requires I use SDL2 and I was excited to finally start attempting to write a program. I downloaded SDL2 and didn't have any problems.

Next I opened a new empty project followed the instructions to add the include folder, lib(x86) folder, and I added the sdl2.lib and sdl2main.lib to the linker.

When I tried to build the project I received the following error.

> 1>MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj) : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'msvcrt.lib'
>       conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
>       1>sdl2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external
>       symbol _SDL_main referenced in function _main
>       1>c:\users\nas\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\Basic SDL\Debug\Basic
>       SDL.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link to the library files.

1. Right click the project and then `properties`
2. Click `VC++ Directories`.
3. Click `include directories`, then the `down arrow`, then `<edit>`.
4. Then add the directory of the include files (where all the .h files are, for example `E:\Visual Studio .NET\SDL2-2.0.3\Include`).
5. Then do the same for the library files by clicking `library directories',`down arrow`,`edit`.  However, you will want to make sure you are targeting x86 (for 32 bit program for example`E:\Visual Studio .NET\SDL2-2.0.3\lib\x86`) or x64 (64bit program, not so common)
6. Then expand `linker` and click `input` on the left hand side.
7. Click additional dependencies, and then edit and add `SDL2.lib` and `SDL2main.lib`.
8. Click `system` under the `linker` heading.
9. Change SubSystem to `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`.
10. Finally make sure the `SDL.dll` file is in the folder of your project debug folder.

Comment: That did the trick. I guess I forgot a couple steps towards the end. Thanks for the help :) .